# rewriting python scipy.integrate.odeint to mimic matlab ode15s

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, ode, odeint

I am new to python, and would like to mimic using the matlab ode15s in python instead of the built-in odeint from scipy.

The code originally is written like this:

```
newRphi = odeint(PSP,Rphi,t,(b,k,F))[-1,:]
```

where PSP is defined as:

```
def PSP(xx,t,b,k,F):
R = xx[0]
phi = xx[1]
Rdot = sum([b[i]*R**(i+1) for i in xrange(len(b))]) + F(t) #indexing from zero
phiDot = 2*pi * k[2]*((R/k[1])**k[0])
yy = hstack((Rdot,phiDot))
return(yy)
```

from reading the instructions on scipy.integrate.odeint(), this function takes arguments in the following format:

```
scipy.integrate.odeint(func, y0, t, args=())
```

which means that `func=PSP, y0=Rphi, t=t, args=(b,k,f)`
So Rphi goes into PSP function, and gets integrated and becomes yy and comes out, and this function does it repeatedly for every element of t.

Now I want to translate it into something that would mimic ode15s from matlab. From reading some other treads, I found out that I can do that using

```
ode.set_integrator('vode', method='bdf', order=15)
```

Now the question becomes, how do I pass the original arguments to this integrator?

I am thinking it would probably look something like this:

```
ode15s = scipy.integrate.ode(f)
ode15s.set_integrator('vode', method='bdf', order=15)
ode15s.set_initial_value(y0, t0)
```

I know that the f is my PSP function, y0 is still the same: Rphi,
Here are my questions:

1. what is my initial value for t0, is it just t[0]?
2. how do I pass the variables (b,k,f) to the function f=PSP?
3. when I call this ode15s, how do I integrate through the vector size of t and collect the final values for yy?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Note that the `15` in `ode15s` does not mean 15th order.  `ode15s` is a variable order algorithm that uses orders from 1 to 5.